# Custom Published Artifacts in Artifactory-TeamCity

Tags: webforms, teamcity, artifactory

I'm working on a project where I need to publish build artifacts produced by **TeamCity** to **Artifactory**

We have a Visual Studio WebForms solution, and the there is no custom Build Script. We use default Visual Studio Build runner in Team City.

In the Build step, under **Deploy Artifacts To Artifactory** section, (*which appears after I integrate Artifactory with TeamCity*) under **Custom published artifacts** I have set the following value:

**WebFormTest\bin=>WebForms\bin

WebFormTest*.aspx=>WebForms**

This creates a folder called **WebForms** in Artifactory and puts .aspx files directly under it, creates a bin sub-directory and puts all files necessary files inside it as expected.

**I actually want to zip the whole WebForms folder and publish that to Artifactory instead of publishing it as a folder. How can I achieve this? Any help is highly appreciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I address this problem is as below:

1. Created 2 Build Configurations called Commit and Publish Artifacts
2. In Commit, I collect artifacts into a custom folder
3. I created snapshot and artifact dependency on Publish Artifacts, with Commit
4. Now in the Artifactory plugin, I zip the folder and publish it to Artifactory repository.

This works exactly how I expect it to work. If anyone has better solutions, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to zip them first using [TeamCity Artifact Packaging feature](http://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2010/02/artifact-packaging-with-teamcity/).